How to wire an RCCB to secure a power supply?
Fellow tinkerers,
reading the manual of my brand new 5V power supply (MeanWell RS-150-5), I've come across the requirement, that I need to secure the PSU with a residual-current circuit breaker (RCCB) between the PSU and mains plug.
My research brought me to this RCCB: Siemens 5SU1356-6KK16, a RCBO (with integrated overcurrent protection), a two-pole device, having two inlets ("1" and "N") and two outlets.
The PSU has inlets "L", "N" and "Ground".

from the colors I chose, you can see I'm located in the EU.
Is it right that the RCBO is wired from below (inlets are on the botton of DIN rail devices?) and the top has outlets, going to load?
Bonus question: I can plug in a Schuko plug both directions, so N and L might be swapped. Is that a problem for the PSU?
I know that I need a certified electrician before "hot" use of my setup, so I will present my circuit to one before plugging everything in the first time - but I want to prepare the cabling.
Update: Here is what the MeanWell manual had to say: 

What is your country? Inline versions may exist that do not require rewiring the existing outlet.

I'm in Germany.

Which manual says you need a RCBO? And doesn't Live have brown color, not black?

As said: the original manual that came with the MeanWell PSU - believe it or not. And although some/many households already have an RCBO on mains, and I'm assembling a plug-in device here, I want to play 100% by the book, also for locations where mains isn't secured by a RCBO.

Can you provide a hyperlink to said manual? Does it state a "File Name" at the lower right of each page? Which?

@greybeard I've updated the question to include a picture of the manual. I really told the truth ;)

@Justme I've updated the question to include a picture of the manual. I really told the truth ;)

I do not read needs an RCBO in the appliance the PS gets integrated to. I read needs an RCBO between the grid and the PS, probably due to no protective isolation.


I've come across the requirement, that I need to secure the PSU with a residual-current circuit breaker

That strikes me as very odd. I can't find any evidence of such a requirement searching online.
In any case, your wiring looks fine, but do remember that the RCBO, the power supply and any wires with only basic insulation need to be inside a suitable enclosure.

(ood is odd.)

I've updated the question to include a picture of the manual. I really told the truth ;) It's German, in section "products for mains connection" (meaning "products not having a factory installed mains power cord").
